# Fitting Log-normal distributions gives negative location

Tags: r, lognormal-distribution, power-law

I'm analysing the distribution of number of posts per user in an online forum (Reddit). I'm trying to fit my distributions to a Power Law and Log-normal distributions to see whether they might follow one or the other.

I use `poweRlaw` R package to do this. As you can see in the ccdf plots, the Log-normal does a better job than the Power Law. Yet, they cannot be Log-normals since their pdf do not have any peak. Inspecting the numerical values of the output, I see that it the parameters are, for instance,  location -26.139555  and scale 6.136564.

How should I interpret this? Might them be log-normal even if their peak is in the first $x$ value (1 post)?

[image]

Comment: I'd revise the title. The fact that you used R appears quite incidental to your question. Also, you want to stop this being closed as being (on a first impression) about R and so off-topic.

Comment: The hard truth not explained well by many who write about this territory is that often no named or brand-name distribution works really well for any variable. At most you have approximations. Note that the discreteness of some of these variables is also a problem in declaring them lognormal. People do everything about that from ignoring it completely to trying to fit a discrete variant on the lognormal.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I modified the title. Your second comment is very helpful to me at this moment of confusion. Indeed, I use a "Discrete Log-normal" (at least they call it like that), which is available in the package

Comment: Not sure I can help you further. I just add that power laws have been vastly oversold by some and much smarter people than I have written to that effect.

Comment: What makes you think that a "discrete lognormal" (whatever that is, but it's clearly not actually a lognormal) will "have a peak" (again, whatever you quite mean by that)?

Comment: I mean that: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/graphs/lognormal_pdf2.png When they (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/poweRlaw.pdf) say the Discrete LN I guess they just do floor(x) and use the lognormal

Comment: By its very definition (and basic properties of probability), the CCDF always has a peak and it's always at the most extreme left value.  I see no plots of the "pdf" to which you refer, either. What, then, are you trying to ask??